# Non compactness of unit open disc in real plane

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

This is immediate from hein borel theorem but i need to find an open cover of unit open disc centred at origin which has no finite subcover.

Comment: Try to think of circles of increasing radius.

Comment: circles in real plane are not open sets.

Comment: You are correct. Open discs is what was meant, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Try open discs with radii $r_n=1-1/n$.